# How to filter datetime using datetime in django?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a Homework model that I want to filter based on the date(date_view) to show the homework. It looks like this-

> Homework model

```
class Homework(models.Model):
    hw_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    homework = models.TextField()
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_view = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

But when I try to filter like this-

```
 hw = Homework.objects.filter(class_id=class_id).filter(date_view__gte='homework__date_added')
```

I get this error-

```
['“homework__date_added” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

I think I am filtering the data in the wrong way. But how should I filter the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to a field with an [**`F`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F

hw = Homework.objects.filter(
    class_id=class_id,
    date_view__gte=F('date_added')
)
```